How to implement and compile the Cyclone EAP library - 802.1x
I am interested in using the CycloneEAP library to implement 802.1X authentication with TLS encryption. However, after reviewing the project in the CycloneEAP repository, I couldn’t find a Makefile or any other files that would allow me to easily compile and run the code.
Could someone provide guidance on how to set up the build environment and run a basic example for authentication using 802.1X with TLS? I’m particularly looking for any examples or documentation on how to compile the project and perform a simple authentication process.
